# Jquery ajax not catching 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, get

I am trying to use AJAX to populate my dropdown list and I am returning a 404 with error message from my controller, and Ajax is not catching it...

My return at the controller is

```
return Response()->json(array('error' => '404 car type not found'), 404);
```

And here is my JS

```
$('document').ready(function () {
$('#car_type').bind('changed.bs.select', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'carclass/'+$('#car_type').val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('status:' + XMLHttpRequest.status + ', status text: ' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
        },
        success: function( json ) {
           $.each(json, function(i, obj){
                $('#car_class').append($('<option>').text(obj.name).attr('value', obj.id));
           });
           $('#car_class').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
});
 });
 });
```

It is returning

```
GET http://localhost:8000/ads/cartype/2 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: The problem would seem to be on the server side then, not your JS.

Comment: Why your ajax is doing a POST request to carclass/... and the return you mention is a GET to cartype/... ?

Comment: "Not catching it" - not catching what?  Is it hitting the `error:` callback but you're not getting the explicit message?  Is it not catching that it's a 404 so hitting the 'success:' callback?

Comment: I am sorry , I realized this was answered already and I marked it duplicated... and it seems that my main problem was #car_type , it should have been #car_brand. I am embarrassed right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `error` block with something like this where `xhr.status` will give you the status code of the response.

```
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    if(xhr.status==404) {
        alert('status:' + xhr.status + ', status text: ' + xhr.statusText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure who copied who and from which other question. Also, this does not answer what the OP is asking.

Comment: I was writing the answer. I am unknown of another answer. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I'm referring to the other answer on this question which had an almost identical description before you edited, and exactly identical code and layout.

Comment: Maybe that was copied @RoryMcCrossan . No idea

Comment: Given you posted 8 seconds after it's likely that you both copied the code from the same place. If it was an SO question it would have been more appropriate to vote to close as a duplicate. That however is moot as your answer is completely irrelevant to the issue

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan will keep that thing in mind. My apologies.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer , because it really helped with fixing an issue, but the main problem I was having was a misspelling on my side.

Comment: @AmirMajid Why mark it as the correct answer if it's not correct?

Comment: @Jackowski it did help with something else related to the same code, and my question was "catching" the error message which is a 404 response

Answer (score 0):

Use `fail()` instead. You could also use the `done()` callback, which is an alternative to `success`.

```js
$.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function(data) {
    $.each(data.responseJSON, function(i, obj) {
            $('#car_class').append($('<option>').text(obj.name).attr('value', obj.id));
    });
    $('#car_class').selectpicker('refresh');
  })
  .fail(function(data) {
    alert('status:' + this.status + ', status text: ' + this.statusText);
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

Comment: 1. The `error` property is not deprecated at all. The link you have added to the documentation even shows this. 2. There is no `fail` property in a `$.ajax()` call. Your code will not work. I presume you meant to use [`fail()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) instead.

Comment: And `fail:` is not a replacement for `error:`, it's a method on the promise, so would be `$.ajax({..}).fail(function() { ... })`

Comment: I can see the confusion over *".fail() method replaces the deprecated .error()"* (from the linked doc).  It means the error method on the promise, not the error *callback* in the ajax call.

Comment: Thanks, I edited to fix my mistake.

Comment: A good edit.  But to be clear, there's no difference between `error:` and `.fail()` other than you can return the promise and add the `.fail()` later.  So you've refactored OP's code, but not fixed it (unless you've added something not explained in the text).